# How to display last 7 days data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

hi can someone help me i want to display last seven day data in my chart it works in this chart type https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series but not working in https://www.highcharts.com/demo/areaspline

for example if today is 05/04/2019 chart will display data from 30-03-2019 to 05-04-2019 (7 days) and areaspline chart has pointStart but how to make it dynamic to display last 7 days? here is my example

```js
$(function() {
 Highcharts.setOptions({lang:{thousandsSep:","}});
 $('#container').highcharts({
  chart:{
   type:'areaspline',
   zoomType: 'x'
   },
  title:{
      text:null,
   margin:0,
   floating:true,
   verticalAlign:'bottom',
   x:0,
   y:0 
  }, 
  xAxis:{
   type:'datetime',
   maxZoom:48*3600*1000 
  },
  plotOptions:{
   series:{
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2019, 03-1, 30),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
  
   }
  },
  yAxis:{
   title:{
    text:null,
   },
  },  
  credits:{
   enabled:false
  },    
  series:[{
   showInLegend:false,
   name:"Dollar",
   data:[1,0.5,3,2,5,2.5]
 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tickPositioner` to return the 7 days positions point of last 7 days.

Point start needs to be set with the current date which you can do it by:

```
pointStart: Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()),
```

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'areaspline',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    maxZoom: 48 * 3600 * 1000,

    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
      var interval = this.options.tickInterval,
        ticks = [],
        count = 0;

      while (min < max) {
        ticks.push(min);
        min += interval;
        count++;
      }

      ticks.info = {
        unitName: 'day',
        count: 1,
        higherRanks: {},
        totalRange: interval * count
      }
      return ticks;
    }

  },


  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    name: "Dollar",
    data: [88, 96, 97, 105, 0,84,86],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // seven days
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

For different datatype:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'areaspline',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'  
  },
  series: [{
    showInLegend: false,
    name: "Dollar",
    data: [
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()),88],
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()+1),89],
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()+2),0],
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()+3),102],
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()+4),114],
    [Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate()+5),120]],
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**API references:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

Comment: thanks so much but why your chart demo display data from 6 Apr to 1 jun it should display last 7 days data from 31 March to 6 April..??

Comment: thanks but not fixed, just a question if my not like data: [88, 96, 97, 105, 106,84,86] but [Date.UTC(2019, 04-1, 02), 0 ], [Date.UTC(2019, 04-1, 03), 35 ], i did it in areaspline if always stay high in 35 even if no data tomorow..it should go down but not

Comment: Added one example  with the datatype suggested, seems like working fine.